# How to store a CSV into a PCollection in Apache Beam

Tags: csv, apache-beam

I have a CSV Data stored at some location. I want to read this data and store it in some PCollection but I am unable to specify the type of PCollection or the way it should be stored in a PCollection

Answer (score 0):

As a quite straitforward way - you can read it as just strings (e.g. `TextIO` for Java SDK will return a `PCollection<String>`) and then parse it with your own `PTransform` into required format that returns a `PCollection<YourPOJO>` (see an [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/79c067cc625b2f02d32334564e86a6480dd545ff/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/UserScore.java#L242)).